# Mongodb count occurences of an element inside the array from group

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a problem where I want to get the number of occurences of a certain element in an array as i group them.
Here is my schema:

```
{
   "name": "John Doe",
   "age": 20,
   "address": "Nasipit, Talamban, Cebu City, Cebu",
   "visitors": [
     {
       "_id": {
         "$oid": "5de5a8271a91ca42fc5fc593"
       },
       "firstname": "Jane Doe",
       "lastname": "Tanilon",
       "address": "California",
       "date": "December 3rd 2019, 8:11:19 am"
     },
     {
       "_id": {
         "$oid": "5de5a8271a91ca42fc5fc593"
       },
       "firstname": "Nice",
       "lastname": "One",
       "address": "California",
       "date": "December 3rd 2019, 8:11:19 am"
     }
     ]
}
```

I tried making to group them:

```
db.visitors.aggregate({
    $group: {_id: '$visitors.address',count:{$sum:1}}
})
```

And the result is :

> { "_id" : [ "California", "California"], "count" : 1 }

And I want to count occurences of California in the array like this one:

> { "_id" : "California, "count" : 2 }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expression `'$visitors.address'` returns an array while you need to count visitors array documents separately. To do that you need to [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) that array before running `$group`:

```
db.visitors.aggregate([
    { $unwind: "$visitors" },
    {
        $group: {_id: '$visitors.address',count:{$sum:1}}
    }
])
```

Comment: I never used $unwind before since I am new to MongoDB, anyways thank you for saving my life!

Answer (score 1):

The following aggregation query counts all the occurances of "California" in all documents.

```
var INPUT_PARAM = "California"

db.test.aggregate( [
{ 
  $unwind: "$visitors" 
},
{ 
  $group: { 
      _id: null, 
      count: { 
          $sum: { 
              "$cond": [ 
                  { "$eq": [ "$visitors.address", INPUT_PARAM ] }, 
                    1, 
                    0 
              ] 
          } 
      } 
  } 
},
{ 
  $project: { 
      _id: INPUT_PARAM, 
      count: 1 
  } 
}
] )
```

The *result* is: `{ "count" : 3, "_id" : "California" }`, when the *input* documents are:

```
{ _id: 11,
   "name": "John Doe",
   "address": "Nasipit, Talamban, Cebu City, Cebu",
   "visitors": [
     {
       "_id": 1,
       "firstname": "Jane Doe",
       "address": "California",
     },
     {
       "_id": 2,
       "firstname": "Nice",
       "address": "California",
     },
       {"_id": 3,
       "firstname": "Jack",
       "address": "Texas",
     }
    ]
},
{ _id: 22,
   "name": "Miller",
   "address": "14, North 5th St., New York",
   "visitors": [
     {
       "_id": 95,
       "firstname": "ABC",
       "address": "California",
     },
       { "_id": 96,
       "firstname": "XYZ",
       "address": "Maine",
     }
    ]
}
```